# How to efficiently specify nested relationships in ember-data?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, emberfire

I have a nested model as such:

```
var School = DS.Model.extend({
    classrooms: DS.hasMany('classroom', {async: true})
});

var Classroom = DS.Model.extend({
    students: DS.hasMany('student', {async: true}),
    school: DS.belongsTo('school', {async: true})
});

var Student = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    classroom: DS.belongsTo('classroom', {async: true})
});
```

I am using firebase as a backend, and I understand it is advisable to denormalize the schema for efficiency sake. Is there any utility in explicitly specifying the relationship

```
var Student = DS.Model.extend({
    school: DS.belongsTo('school', {async: true});
});
```

for the `Student` model, even though this is implied by each `Student` belonging to a `Classroom` and each `Classroom` belonging to a `School`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You shouldn't need to provide nested relationship information unless model in question is directly accessible from the root object (hope that makes sense).

The only "benefit" of doing so is that in your case the `student` model will be loaded when the `school` data is being loaded rather than waiting until the `classroom` data is loaded. However, this will provide a data structure that is not reflective of your intentions and so I wouldn't advocate doing this.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a computed property or a binding to get what you're after - something like

```
school: Ember.computed.alias('classroom.school')
schoolBinding: 'classroom.school'
```

It wouldn't be a DS.belongsTo because the data wouldn't actually contain a school property